# Unexpected output writing to csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have a directory containing .ann (annotation files). I am calculating the distance between every continuous element and storing it in a dictionary, that part is all good I get the desired output.

The problem is that I need this data in csv files to be processed later in MatLab. I get empty csv files that only contain the number of rows in the data. Pardon me if you don't quite understand and also for being inexperienced in Python.

```
import collections
import os
import csv

path = "C:/Users/ernes/Documents/MATLAB/Annotations_Subject2/"

def s_distance(spikes):
    dist = []
    for times in range(1, len(spikes)):
        dist.append(round(spikes[times] - spikes[times - 1], 4))
    return dist

def write_to_csv(file_name, datos):
    csv_file = open(file_name+'.csv', 'w', newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(datos)

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.ann'):
        print(file)
        fileID = open(path+file, 'r')
        data = {}
        for line in fileID:
            (value, key) = line.split()
            data.setdefault(int(key), []).append(float(value))
        data = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(data.items()))
        for items in data:
            print(items, ' ', s_distance(data[items]))
        write_to_csv(file, data)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: You need to use a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents) (not `csv.writer`) in order to pass a dictionary to `writer.writerow()`.

Comment: Off-topic: I also suggest you use `for file in glob.glob(path+'*.ann')`. That way all the matching files will already have `path` in them (as well as filename). Note, too, that the `else`/`continue` is unnecessary.

Comment: Also off-topic, but I suggest using the `with open(...) as csv_file:` syntax for opening your files because it will automatically close the file at the end of scope and is a little cleaner.  You can do it for both reading and writing a file.

Comment: So in your case it looks like you passed the whole dictionary into your `write_to_csv` method and expected it to loop the dictionary and write the values out, but that's not how it works.  You'll have to loop the dictionary keys and write out each row via the `csv.DictWriter` that @martineau linked to.  Also, your value for the key is a list, so you will most likely have to join all the values together into a single string when you print.  It would help if you give us a sample of your annotation file as well.

Comment: If you'd like an actual answer, please see [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to fix.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I see now what the problem was, I just got it to work!!